how I show a Summary result?
How can I export a summary result, stargazer is not working.
stargazer(summary(my_plm_pooling_1, vcov = function(x) vcovHC(x)), type='text')
result (translated to english):

Error in dimnames(x) <- dn :
length of 'dimnames' [2] is not equal to the size of the array


Hello Luiza. Welcome to Stackoverflow. To help you, we need more information. Please provide a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

‘stargazer’ is a terrible package. I strongly recommend against using it. Use anything else instead, e.g. ‘modelsummary’ or ‘texreg’.

Something that worked for me before is the function capture_output.
It goes like
out_summary <- summary(my_plm_pooling_1, vcov = function(x) vcovHC(x))
capture.output(out_summary, file = 'output_summary.txt')

